# Safari bug at textField

Tags: safari, textfield

On my chat website there is a simple `<input type='text' ...`, but sometimes only Safari (Mac) shows weird "shadows" or whatever (always different - sometimes vertical, sometimes horizontally). Is it possible to fix this?

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: Okay, I changed the code now. Before I had JavaScript code for showing a placeholder, if the textfield is not focused. Now I changed it using the placeholder-attribute and it's working! The old Script:
`OnFocus="if(this.value=='Enter something'){ this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#1f1f1f'; }" OnBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value = 'Enter something'; this.style.color='gray' }"`